# Gson exclusion strategy and custom serialization

Tags: java, gson

I am using Gson custom serialization on my persistent object. At the same time, I am also using serialization exclusion strategy. The code is as shown below :

```
public class GsonFactory {

    public static Gson build(Type type, final List<String> fieldExclusions,
            final List<Class<?>> classExclusions) {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                return fieldExclusions == null ? false : fieldExclusions
                        .contains(f.getName());
            }

            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return classExclusions == null ? false : classExclusions
                        .contains(clazz);
            }
        });
        // Uncommenting this line will produce error
        // gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(type,
        // new PersistentObjectJsonSerializer());
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }
}

class PersistentObjectJsonSerializer implements
        JsonSerializer<PersistentObject> {

    public JsonElement serialize(PersistentObject src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {
        src.setDT_RowId(src.getId());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJsonTree(src);
    }

}
```

However if I uncomment the `gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(type, new PersistentObjectJsonSerializer());`, upon creation of `gsonBuilder` will give the following error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.equals(TypeToken.java:284)
    java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:305)
    java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Collections.java:1979)
    com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:337)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:883)
```

My PersistentObject java class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class PersistentObject implements Serializable {

....

@Transient
protected long DT_RowId;
// getters, setters not shown

...

}
```

This is how I call the GsonFactory.build in GenericHibernateDAO:

```
public abstract class GenericHibernateDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> {

private Class<T> persistentClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public GenericHibernateDAO() {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}


public String listAsJsonResponse(){
    ...
    // testing start
    List<Class<?>> classExclusions = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    classExclusions.add(Role.class);
    List<String> fieldExclusions = new ArrayList<String>();
    fieldExclusions.add("users");
    fieldExclusions.add("password");
    Gson gson = GsonFactory.build(persistentClass,fieldExclusions, null);
    ...
    return jsonResponse.toString();
}
}
```

The `persistentClass` here refers to `User` class:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO extends GenericHibernateDAO<User, Long> {

}
```

Basically I can't manage to use both function at the same time. Any pointer on what might cause this issue ?

Comment: Could you please provide some more info about the PersitentObject class. Where does this come from (custom class/some library)? 
Also, please post how you call the build method (parameters).

Comment: you seem not to be the only one having gson StackOverflowError issues: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/kXPJJ_um3cs moreover, in another report: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=96 hey even admit having some recursion causing StackOverflow, my recommendation would be to try some other Json librabry in java. I'd recommend: Jackson (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)

Comment: @Marek Dec: I have updated the code

Comment: @Peter: I will try Jackson tonight and come back with the result

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but maybe my answer could still help someone.

You create a new Gson object in your serializer. This Gson object doesn't know your ExclusionStrategies for the PersistentObjects anymore. If your PersistantObject has attribute objects which will lead to an PersistentObject again (in your case the users might have attributes of persistantObject), than you will run into an endless loop and into the stackoverflow exception.

One solution is to add exclusion strategies again to the gson object in your serializer. But don't add the serializer to this gson object again!

```
class PersistentObjectJsonSerializer implements
    JsonSerializer<PersistentObject> {

    public JsonElement serialize(PersistentObject src, Type typeOfSrc,
        JsonSerializationContext context) {
        src.setDT_RowId(src.getId());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        //add exclusion strategy here again
        return gson.toJsonTree(src);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gson is open source and you can get the source code. Why dont you do that and follow the code to see in which point it throws the exception? It seems like gson falls in an infinite loop. It s true that gson uses recursion a lot. If it is actually a bug you can report it to the Gson guys and they will solve it in the next release.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/list